# PHP session resets somehow

Tags: php, session

I am working on a website where it is possible for the current user to choose different cities to look in.. I don't want to keep the city in the URL and I don't want to depend on a cookie, if the client will not accept cookies.. I am doing it in sessions then, but somehow the session stops very early and I don't understand what is wrong..

```
if (isset($_GET['c'])) {
unset($_SESSION['city']); 
$_SESSION['city'] = $_GET['c'];
}
if (empty($_SESSION['city'])) {
$_SESSION['city']='07400';
}
$city = $_SESSION['city'];
```

after I click three pages around, the the city is back to 07400.. In some way.. the Session gets empty.. but I don't know how...

Comment: Probably you forgot to call `session_start()` at the begin of a script.

Comment: Using sessions, your functionality will only be available for users with cookies enabled. The SessionID will be stored in a cookie sent to the browser.

Comment: if the GET["c"] in your first IF is empty the session variable will be too, then it goes to the second IF and get the values 07400

Comment: That `unset()` is pointless, since you're just assigning something again on the next line.

Comment: If you need to do anything without cookie, pass the session id via URL querystring.

Comment: what's the value of $_GET['c']?

Comment: Is there any chance you are moving between www.abc.com and abc.com between pages? If so those are seen as 2 different domains when it comes to sessions (and are maintained separately) unless you force it otherwise.

Comment: I have the session started at the top of every page.. there is not difference between the links.. they are linking to each other as following: home.php, search.php. Then I have a list of cities and the value passed with the link is the current $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] pus a zip code to identify the city selected in the query variable 'c'. The unset is now removed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on the script long enough, I found out, that nothing was wrong with the city script... Nothing was wrong with the Sessions.. But because of a scripting mistake later in the script, it destroyed the $_SESSION['city'].. Thanks for all the replies.. And thanks for the tips to look for mistakes, and maybe a changed session id...

Answer (score 1):

Without the possibility to test/debug your project, it is very difficult to find out the problem. Nevertheless this could help getting you on the right track:

I would **give out the session-id** on every page you are requesting like that: `print(session_id());`.

If the **session-id changes**, you have lost your session and should check how the id is passed and the session is recreated (cookie, id in url, session_start). I would also write the code `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the begin of the pages, to see if you get a header-already-sent warning.

If the **session-id remains constant**, the session is recreated correctly. Then i would search the project for code, that writes to the session and possibly resets the variable.